# Sending sqlite data from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-studio

I am currently working on a project and I need assistance.

I want to send the name, total quantities and total price of that quantity of a product in my to my add to cart activity.

In the add to cart activity, I want to calculate the total amount of the items in the cart and then send to my sales activity which will store the items and the prices for every item sent from the cart.

MainActivity....

@Override
    public void onListClick(final ItemInfo item) {

```
    numberPicker = new MaterialNumberPicker.Builder(self)
            .minValue(1)
            .maxValue(100)
            .defaultValue(1)
            .backgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
            .separatorColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
            .textColor(Color.BLACK)
            .textSize(20)
            .enableFocusability(false)
            .wrapSelectorWheel(true)
            .build();

    new MaterialDialog.Builder(self)
            .title(item.getItemName())
            .customView(numberPicker, true)
            .positiveColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTurquoise))
            .negativeColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
            .positiveText("Ok")
            .negativeText("Cancel")
            .cancelable(false)
            .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                    MaterialDialog mMaterialDialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(self)
                            .title("Total")
                            .customView(R.layout.layout_popup_sales, true)
                            .autoDismiss(false)
                            .positiveColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTurquoise))
                            .negativeColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
                            .positiveText("Add to Cart")
                            .negativeText("Cancel")
                            .cancelable(false)
                            .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
```

What code should be above to send to cart activity??

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Added To Cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

```
                            .onNegative(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            })
                            .build();


                    TextView mPopupName = (TextView) mMaterialDialog.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.layout_popup_sales_name);
                    mPopupName.setText(item.getItemName());
                    TextView mPopupQuantity = (TextView) mMaterialDialog.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.layout_popup_sales_quantity);
                    mPopupQuantity.setText("(" + numberPicker.getValue() + Constant.UNITS + " - " + Constant.NGN + item.getItemPrice() + ")");
                    TextView mPopupPrice = (TextView) mMaterialDialog.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.layout_popup_sales_price);
                    mPopupPrice.setText(Constant.NGN + (numberPicker.getValue() * item.getItemPrice()));
                    mMaterialDialog.show();
                }
            })
            .onNegative(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you will have multiple products and atleast 2 activities (one showing the list and one its info) . You should create a static array list of a POJO class having variables of details ie( name, total quantities and total price of that quantity of a product) and when a user add some product you make a entry in this list . And in cart access this arraylist to do your work and send the calculated total amount to my sales activity .

Comment: ''when a user add some product you make a entry in this list . And in cart access this arraylist to do your work and send the calculated total amount to my sales activity"

Can you show me an example code of how to carry this out?
I am actually stuck here

Comment: It will take time to make a example but will try to revert back today

Comment: I have taken static data for simplicity you can always replace them with dynamic data . The link for example project is https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvceoMt7FbgGahYsh7neL5Um6Tc?e=MpXKhJ . You can always contact me @ shahaashit26@gmail.com for any further guidance . Mark the answer correct and give upvote if you find this helpful .

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot!!!
I sent you a mail. Kindly read and revert. Thanks

Comment: I want to create an activity to store the sales from the database. After **selling all products that was added to cart, it should display empty cart and store that sales in one row** and also have the option of exporting it to excel....